# BE custom authenticator not being invoked on WSO2 GS

Tags: authentication, wso2

Our requirement is to have email id as the username for the login. We used the blogger post found at this [link](http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.in/2011/08/carbon-authentication-framework.html#comment-form). We built the business logic in the `customauthenticator` class file, and just deployed the BE authentication piece. We used the dropins folder as suggested and  modified the `authenitcators.xml` file in the conf/advanced directory.

We tried with both `disabled=true` and `disabled=false`, and lower and higher priorities. There was simply no change. It didn't appear that the jar file was being picked up. Is there any other configuration that we are missing in order to get the custom authentication activated? Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to write a custom authenticator for your requirement.

If you enable JDBCUserStoreManager in user-mgt.xml and make the following property to true, then email id will be used as username.

Property name="IsEmailUserName"

Thanks,
Hasini.

Comment: Our requirement is to authenticate against external LDAP. Will enabling email id as property for JDBCUserStoreManager  work for ldap user store manager as well ? I will give this a try and let you know.